# Why the action group on fuctions is $(\lambda \cdot f)(x) = f(\lambda^{-1}x)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I'm a beginner on representation theory and group theory, and maybe my language is not too technically correct.

But I just want to know why the action of a group elements $\lambda \in \Lambda$ on functions $f \in M $ is: 
$$(\lambda \cdot  f)(x) = f(\lambda^{-1}x)$$

In the basic texts I read it appears like a definition, or they don't talk too much about it, just works. But it seems to me a non-trivial expression, specially the $\lambda^{-1}$ on the argument. What's the intuition to understand the expression? Is there a prove for this relation?

Comment: Let's have $\mathbb{R}$ act on real functions. The action of $r$ on the function $f$ will shift the function to the right by $r$. That is $(rf)(x) = f(x-r)$. Rewrite this in multiplicative notation.

Comment: Maybe it's more intuitive if you think of it as $(\lambda \cdot f)(\lambda x) = f(x)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's to satisfy the group action axioms, namely the composition one, that
$$(\mu \cdot (\lambda \cdot f)) = ((\mu\lambda) \cdot f).$$

If we write $g(x) = f(\lambda^{-1}x)$, we have
$$ (\mu \cdot (\lambda \cdot f))(x) = (\mu \cdot g)(x) = g(\mu^{-1}x) = f(\lambda^{-1}\mu^{-1}x) = f((\mu\lambda)^{-1}x) = ((\mu\lambda) \cdot f)(x), $$
as it should be. If you don't use the inverse, you get the wrong order in the product in the composition.